# Parsing .gql files as DocumentNode in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, graphql, apollo-server

I have the following typeDefs in type-defs.gql:

```
type A {
  name: String
}

type Query {
  a: A
}
```

If I were to setup my apollo server this way then I'd get SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier for the gql file:

```
import { ApolloServer} from "apollo-server";
import typeDefs from "./type-defs.gql";

const resolvers = {};

const config = {
  resolvers: resolvers,
  typeDefs: typeDefs,
};
const server = new ApolloServer(config);
server.listen().then(({ url }) => console.log(`Server running at: ${url}`));
```

But if I setup the server the following way everything just works fine:

```
import { ApolloServer, gql} from "apollo-server";

const resolvers = {};
const typeDefs = gql`
  type A {
    name: String
  }

  type Query {
    a: A
  }
`;

const config = {
  resolvers: resolvers,
  typeDefs: typeDefs,
};
const server = new ApolloServer(config);
server.listen().then(({ url }) => console.log(`Server running at: ${url}`));
```

My gql.d.ts contains the following:

```
declare module "*.gql" {
  import { DocumentNode } from "graphql";

  const value: DocumentNode;
  export default value;
}
```

I'd much rather prefer to use a gql file instead of writing the typeDefs directly in my server.ts file.
Could anyone help me resolve this, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to make a working solution by using loadSchemaSync from @graphql-tools.

```
import { ApolloServer } from "apollo-server";
import { loadSchemaSync } from "@graphql-tools/load";
import { GraphQLFileLoader } from "@graphql-tools/graphql-file-loader";
import { addResolversToSchema } from "@graphql-tools/schema";

const resolvers = {};
const schema = loadSchemaSync("./src/**/*.gql", {
  loaders: [new GraphQLFileLoader()],
});

const config = {
  schema: addResolversToSchema({schema, resolvers}),
};
const server = new ApolloServer(config);
server.listen().then(({ url }) => console.log(`Server running at: ${url}`));
```